# How to generate Crud operations for a graphql API in Java/Kotlin (without Spring...)

Tags: crud, openapi-generator, graphql-java

I am looking for a way to generate basic CRUD operations based on a given graphql schema to be used for a GUI or a test automation in Java.

For instance the server is configured on client side and has access to a schema
like https://github.com/marmelab/GraphQL-example/blob/master/schema.graphql
I would like to create CRUD operation for all types like Notifications that allows setting all fields. So for Java that would be methods like the ones listed below.

Background: I work on a project where many developers created function using graphql calls more or less directly in the top level functions. This makes the code very hard to read. (Much more since the calls are not written in a consistent way)

Wrapping the api calls in functions on a lower level would free the higher level code of lower level implementation and make it much more readable.

In addition a generator would allow to update changes in the schema automatically. Although it will still need manual adaption on the higher level, it would probably reduce the cumbersome and errorprone manual adaption of the graphql calls.

I found frameworks that create graphql schema from java code like SPQR (https://github.com/leangen/graphql-spqr), and https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/generators/graphql-schema/ seems also to create the graphql schema.    But from the client side the situation is the other way around: We are given a graphl schema and would like to have a generated java code to write the requests and read the responses instead of writing boiler plate code...

I found https://github.com/graphql-java-generator/graphql-maven-plugin-project and other fancy ways to map graphql calls - in Spring. But if it is not possible to introduce Spring, is there another tool that would do the job?

```
createNotification( date: Date, type: String) {
    [code for graphlcall] 
}

const String updateNotificationMutation = "mutation UpdateNotification(\$id: String, \date: Date, \$type: String!) { updateNotification($id, $date, $type) }

Notification updateNotification( iD: String, date: Date, type: String) {
    //code for graphlcall like
UpdateNotificationMutation mutation = new UpdateNotificationMutation(id, type);
Notification updatedNotification = notificationService.updateNotification(mutation);    
}



findNotification( iD: String, date: Date, type: String) {
    [code for graphlcall] 
}

deleteNotification( iD: String, date: Date, type: String) {
    [code for graphlcall] 
}
```